# Fibonacci n-step number sequences with R

Tags: r, fibonacci

[Fibonacci n-step number sequences](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fibonaccin-StepNumber.html) is a generalization of Fibonacci numbers where you add more than two of the preceding numbers together. I try to write a function in R that does that.

First the classical Fibonacci numbers:

```
fib <- function(n){
  fib <- vector()
  fib[1] <- 1
  fib[2] <- 1
  for(i in 3:n){
    fib[i] <- fib[i-1] + fib[i-2]
  }
  return(fib)
}

fib(7)
## [1]  1  1  2  3  5  8 13
```

Next the so called Tribonacci numbers:

```
fib3 <- function(n){
  fib <- vector()
  fib[1] <- 1
  fib[2] <- 1
  fib[3] <- 2
  for(i in 4:n){
    fib[i] <- fib[i-1] + fib[i-2] + fib[i-3]
  }
  return(fib)
}

fib3(7)
## [1]  1  1  2  4  7 13 24
```

and so on...

The initial values are powers of 2, so for n=3 it is 1,1,2, for n=4 it is 1,1,2,4, for n=5 it is 1,1,2,4,8 and so on.

So my idea is to modify the above function on the fly, especially the number of arguments in the for-loop, yet I don't know enough of R to achieve that efficiently.

**My question**
How can I modify the above code to create any Fibonacci n-step number sequence?

**Additional info**
Many more details and different implementations can be found here... unfortunately not in R: [Rosetta code Fibonacci n-step number sequences](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fibonacci_n-step_number_sequences#Julia)

Comment: How do you determine the starting values for the first n numbers in the sequence?  Are you willing to allow these to be user-supplied, or is there some rule for obtaining them?

Comment: @JacobSocolar: Thank you for your question: The initial values are basically powers of 2, so for n=3 it is 1,1,2, for n=4 it is 1,1,2,4, for n=5 it is 1,1,2,4,8 and so on. - I also edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the user supplies `n` (the step-number) and `starting`, a vector of exactly `n` starting values, and `K`, the desired number of elements in the sequence, you could do something like the following.

```
n <- 7
K <- 100
starting <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)

fibn <- function(n, K, starting){
 sequence <- vector(mode='numeric', length=K)
 sequence[1:n] <- starting
 for(i in (n+1):K){
  sequence[i] <- sum(sequence[(i-n):(i-1)])
 }
 return(sequence)
}
```